# using google chart api with sql

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

so i'm trying to use sql statements in google charts api, but i'm not sure how to do this... i know we arent supposed to use javascript for sql (although it is possible) s i was wondering how in the world i'm supposed to use my data in my database for the chart. i already came up with the php statements which the elements are already ready in a array for google charts api to read, but the example i'm seeing i'm not sure if i could just pass it in like any other javascript function, heres my example...

```
  <html>
  <head>
      <!--Load the AJAX API-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table, 
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

      // Create the data table.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
      data.addRows([
        ['Mushrooms', 3],
        ['Onions', 1],
        ['Olives', 1], 
        ['Zucchini', 1],
        ['Pepperoni', 2]
      ]);

      // Set chart options
      var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                     'width':400,
                     'height':300};

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

if i have an array from my php code, how do i end up sending it to drawchart when .setonloadcallback(drawchart) takes no parameters? i already tried putting parameters in there and it would just break the whole segment of code (chart would just not show up) any thoughts would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should transfer the data from the backend (PHP/MySQL) to the frontend (Javascript).

1. If you **don't need to do it asynchronously**, you can just copy them
   among the Javascript code and use the array in Google Chart Api's
   request. Beware, you should respect the Javascript syntax while copying the code and that is certainly your problem here. Synchronously here means that the chart won't change unless you reload the page.
2. If you need to do it **asynchronously** to use Ajax:

   - From the Javascript you call asynchronously the PHP script on the backend that retrieve some data from the database
   - You get the data back from that PHP script and then send them to the Google Chart Api